# How to get the inner object array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I tried with flatMap using lodash.

```
       const object = [
    {
        "id": '11',
        "contactTypes":[
            { 
                "name":"test12",
                "value":"test12"
            },
            { 
                "name":"test13",
                "value":"test13"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": '12',
        "contactSucUnsuc":[
            { 
                "name":"test44",
                "value":"test44"
            },
            { 
                "name":"test45",
                "value":"test45"
            },
        ]
    },
]
parseJson(object){
    object.forEach(function(el, i) {
      Object.keys(el).map((key,index)=>{
        if(index==1){
          const allUsers = flatMap(el, function(o){return o[key]});
          console.log(allUsers)
        }
      })
    });
  }
```

output should be all inner object grouped in one array. I tried with thw above code i am getting undefined is there any possibleltiy to do that. Note the inner object key will be diffrent it not be same.

Comment: Can you please include your expected output?

Comment: which property would `if(index==1)` be do you think? (your code declares an invalid object ...missing something?

Comment: can you also include a valid object?

Comment: What should the output look like?

Comment: @techie18, this object is not valid. Could you please include valid object?

Comment: @Sidhanshu_ object updated above

Comment: @Sidhanshu_  my output should be like `{ "name":"test12","value":"test12"},
            { "name":"test13", "value":"test13"},
            { "name":"test12","value":"test44"},
            { "name":"test13", "value":"test45"}`

Comment: @techie18, Answered a classic way! I might come up 1-2 liner in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirement, this should work!

```
  var newObj = [];
  for (let i of object) {
                for (let j of Object.values(i)) {
                    if (Array.isArray(j)) {
                        newObj = [...newObj, ...j]
                        console.log(newObj)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Another Shorter approach :

```
 newObj = []
            object.forEach(x =>{
                 Object.values(x).filter(y => {
                     if(Array.isArray(y)) newObj = [...newObj, ...y]
                 } )
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```js
var data = [{
        "id": '11',
        "contactTypes": [{
                "name": "test12",
                "value": "test12"
            },
            {
                "name": "test13",
                "value": "test13"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": '12',
        "contactSucUnsuc": [{
                "name": "test44",
                "value": "test44"
            },
            {
                "name": "test45",
                "value": "test45"
            },
        ]
    },
];
var expectedList = [];

data.forEach(function(el, i) {
    Object.keys(el).map((key, index) => {
        var temp = el[key];
        if (typeof temp === 'object') {
            temp.forEach(function(obj) {
                expectedList.push(obj);
            })
        }
    })
});

console.log(expectedList)
```